# How to divide db dates into weeks?

Tags: php, mysql

I have dates in a db. For example, `07/03/2016 (Sunday), 07/04/2016 (Monday)...`

I'm already planning on using a while loop to go through all the dates with

```
while($fetch_content = mysqli_fetch_array($content)) {
...
}
```

Now, when I loop through these dates, how can I divide the information into weeks?

Comment: You can use the [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) object.

Comment: I don't know what divide into weeks means

Comment: 7/3/16-7/9/16 would be one week. 7/10/16 - 7/16/16 would be another week...

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var d=new Date()
var weekday=new Array(7)
weekday[0]="Sunday"
weekday[1]="Monday"
weekday[2]="Tuesday"
weekday[3]="Wednesday"
weekday[4]="Thursday"
weekday[5]="Friday"
weekday[6]="Saturday"
document.write("Today it is " + weekday[d.getDay()])
</script>
```